# Connection to [name of the host name] failed. Host [name of the host name] is unknown. [08001] The connection attempt failed

Tags: datagrip

I am trying to connect datagrip to my remote heroku postgres database but it [doesn't connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53esu.png)

```
 Connection to jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-235-156-60.compute-1.amazonaws.com :5432/d89oi6u1v8vmmo failed.
Host ec2-54-235-156-60.compute-1.amazonaws.com  is unknown.
[08001] The connection attempt failed.
```

I read heroku needs ssl so i provided [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju0pV.png)

Comment: That whitespace between the .com and port looks a bit suspicious.

Comment: thanks. i corrected it. now it shows error as The SSLSocketFactory class provided org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory  could not be instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. The problem was the whitespace between ".com and :". I removed it. It again showed error as

```
 The SSLSocketFactory class provided org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory could not be instantiated
```

I tested it again it started working